# Visual Studio Scheduled Build Trigger

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am using the new Visual Studio build definitions on Visual Studio Online under Build. I would like to run a scheduled build every day for the branch TestingBuildDefinitions1 only if there have been changes in the branch since the previous build.

I cannot find the option to run scheduled builds only if there have been changes. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh190718.aspx#trigger_schedule) says there should be a **"Build even if nothing has changed since the previous build"** checkbox. However, the [new screen](http://i.imgur.com/HzlFcuI.png) does not have this checkbox.

Comment: The documentation link you sent if for the XAML builds and not for the new style VSO-Agent builds. This feature is not yet available for the new builds it seems. The documentation for the new engine can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/vs/define-build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is referring to the old Xaml based builds, while the UI you are using is for the new VSO Build vNext, which does not have the functionality you are looking for.
If you want to create a new Xaml based build, you will need to do it from the Visual Studio client (it cannot be done from the portal).

Start by clicking on `Builds` in `Team Explorer`
[image]

Comment: To add to that, the documentation for the new build system is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/vs/define-build